# C++ function to approximate sine using taylor series expansion

Tags: c++, math, series, trigonometry

Hi I am trying to calculate the results of the Taylor series expansion for sine to the specified number of terms.

I am running into some problems

- Your task is to implement makeSineToOrder(k)
- This is templated by the type of values used in the calculation.
- It must yield a function that takes a value of the specified type and
- returns the sine of that value (in the specified type again)

```
double factorial(double long order){

#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <cmath> 

double fact = 1;

for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++){

    fact *= i;

}

return fact;
}

  

  

  void makeSineToOrder(long double order,long double precision = 15){
double value = 0;

for(int n = 0; n < precision; n++){

    value += pow(-1.0, n) * pow(num, 2*n+1) / factorial(2*n + 1);

}

return value; 
int main()

    {
         using namespace std;
        long double pi = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510L;
        for(int     order = 1;order < 20; order++) {
              auto sine = makeSineToOrder<long double>(order);
               cout << "order(" << order << ") -> sine(pi) = " << setprecision(15) << sine(pi) << endl;
          }
          return 0;
       }
```

I tried debugging

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: move those includes to the top of the file for a start

Comment: This code won't even compile, so it's no wonder it doesn't give any correct answer(s). And debugging would be difficult when there isn't any program to debug.

Comment: its hard to know what is just bad code pasting and what is an actual problem. Can you check that the code in teh question is what you intend it to be. The includes are in the wrong place, the 'retrun value' is wrong too

Answer (score 0):

here is a version that at least compiles and gives some output

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <cmath> 
using namespace std;
double factorial(double long num) {
    double fact = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        fact *= i;
    }
    return fact;
}

double makeSineToOrder(double num, double precision = 15) {
    double value = 0;

    for (int n = 0; n < precision; n++) {

        value += pow(-1.0, n) * pow(num, 2 * n + 1) / factorial(2 * n + 1);

    }
    return value;
}

int main(){

    long double pi = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510L;
    for (int order = 1; order < 20; order++) {
        auto sine = makeSineToOrder(order);
        cout << "order(" << order << ") -> sine(pi) = " << setprecision(15) << sine << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

not sure what that odd `sine(pi)` was supposed to be doing

Comment: If I see it right problem statement wants templates with generic type making your solution having the same issues as the OPs ones

Comment: @Spektre well OP code wasnt even close to compiling, I just fixed that

Answer (score 0):

Apart the obvious syntax errors (the includes should be before your factorial header) in your code:

1. I see no templates in your code which your assignment clearly states to use

   so I would expect template like:

   ```
   <class T> T mysin(T x,int n=15){ ... }
   ```
2. using `pow` for generic datatype is not safe

   because inbuild `pow` will use float or double instead of your generic type so you might expect rounding/casting problems or even unresolved function in case of incompatible type.

   To remedy that you can rewrite the code to not use `pow` as its just consequent multiplication in loop so why computing pow again and again?
3. using factorial function is waste

   you can compute it similar to `pow` in the same loop no need to compute the already computed multiplications again and again. Also not using template for your factorial makes the same problems as using `pow`

so putting all together using this formula:

[image: taylor]

along with templates and exchanging pow,factorial functions with consequent iteration I got this:

```
template <class T> T mysin(T x,int n=15)
    {
    int i;
    T y=0;      // result
    T x2=x*x;   // x^2
    T xi=x;     // x^i
    T ii=1;     // i!
    if (n>0) for(i=1;;)
        {
        y+=xi/ii; xi*=x2; i++; ii*=i; i++; ii*=i; n--; if (!n) break;
        y-=xi/ii; xi*=x2; i++; ii*=i; i++; ii*=i; n--; if (!n) break;
        }
    return y;
    }
```

so factorial `ii` is multiplied by `i+1` and `i+2` every iteration and power `xi` is multiplied by `x^2` every iteration ... the sign change is hard coded so for loop does 2 iterations per one run (that is the reason for the `break;`)

As you can see this does not use anything funny so you do not need any includes for this not even math ...

You might want to add `x=fmod(x,6.283185307179586476925286766559)` at the start of `mysin` in order to use more than just first period however in that case you have to ensure `fmod` implementation uses `T` or compatible type to it ... Also the 2*pi constant should be in target precision or higher

beware too big `n` will overflow both `int` and generic type `T` (so you might want to limit `n` based on used type somehow or just use it wisely).

Also note on 32bit `float`s you can not get better than 5 decimal places no matter what `n` is with this kind of computation.

Btw. there are faster and more accurate methods of computing goniometrics like [Chebyshev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) and [CORDIC](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjkxIvey_z2AhXh8rsIHTRlCecQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCORDIC&usg=AOvVaw3xgZ10JrbjJR1R5J7fTIZw)