# Problems with precision loss in my cosine function

Tags: c, math, precision, trigonometry, factorial

This is my task:

> Write a C function to evaluate the series // cos(x) = x-(x2 /2!)+(x4
> /4!)-(x6 /6!)+... etc. Variable realNuber use radians instead of
> degrees

I lose precision, but I don't understand where. The answer with realNumber = 60 must be 0.500, but I've 0.501. Please help.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "inttypes.h"

double power(float N, uint32_t P){
    double buffer = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < P; ++i) {
        buffer *= N;
    }

    return buffer;
}

float factorial(float number){
    float result = number;

    if (number == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < number - 1; ++i) {
        result *= i + 1;
    }

    return result;
}

float cos(float x){
    float result = x * (3.14159265359 / 180.);
    float polar = -1;

    for (int i = 2; i < 10; i += 2) {
        result += power(result, i) / factorial(i) * polar;
        polar *= -1;
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void){
    float realNumber = 0;
    float result = 0;

    scanf("%f", &realNumber);

    result = cos(realNumber);

    printf("%.13f", result);
}
```

I tried making changes in function cos(); maybe the problem is in a different place?

Comment: Have you tried running your code line-by-line in a debugger while monitoring the values of all variables, in order to determine in which line the floating point deviation becomes unacceptable? If you did not try this, then you may want to read this: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471)

Comment: Unless it's part of your assignment, don't write your own functions, use the ones already available in standard C. Like [`pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) and [`cos`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/cos).

Comment: Also don't use `float` for floating point numbers or calculations. Use `double`.

Comment: I completely disagree with the suggested duplicate. This has nothing to do with the floating-point representation.

Comment: `float` is honestly pretty trash and unless you're doing something which is largely insensitive to precision, like ML or some aspects of 3D rendering, you should be using `double`.

Comment: You are passing the wrong value as the first argument of `power`. It should be the angle in radians, not the current result.

Comment: Also it's probably better to do the multiplication first and then the division in `x * (3.14159265359 / 180.);`. It should be `x * 3.14159265359 / 180.;`

Comment: The moment I see a trig function Taylor series representation with a factorial() function call I know it's naive and likely to be wrong.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71908936/2521214 on how to improve speed and performance a bit by not recomputing the same factorial again and again ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You originally wrote:

> Write a C function to evaluate the series // cos(x) = x-(x2 /2!)+(x4 /4!)-(x6 /6!)

But that is ***NOT*** the Taylor series for cos.

The proper formula is:

[image]

*(Note the `1` in the first term not an `x`)* 
[Source](https://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m142/handouts/10sTaylorPolySeries.pdf)

With a correction to your Taylor series, and some other fix up, I got:

### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5392KB
0.4999999701977
```

My Code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "inttypes.h"

// No Changes
double power(float N, uint32_t P){
    double buffer = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < P; ++i) {
        buffer *= N;
    }

    return buffer;
}

// No Changes
float factorial(float number){
    float result = number;

    if (number == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < number - 1; ++i) {
        result *= i + 1;
    }

    return result;
}

// Minor changes, explained in comments
float cos(float x){
    x = x * (3.14159265359 / 180.); // Convert Degrees to Radians
    float result = 1;               // Taylor series starts with 1, not with x !!! 
    float polar = -1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i += 2) {
        result += power(x, i) / factorial(i) * polar;
        polar *= -1;
    }

    return result;
}

// Skipped the scanf in favor of hard-coded value, for simplicity.
int main(void){
    float realNumber = 60;
    float result = 0;

    result = cos(realNumber);

    printf("%.13f", result);
}
```

When I re-wrote the cos function to eliminate using power and factorial functions, I got this:

```
double cos(float x){
    x = x * (3.14159265359 / 180.); // Convert Degrees to Radians
    double num   = 1;  // Numerator of the fraction (x^2, x^4...)
    int    sgn   = +1; // Sign, alternating -1, +1
    uint64_t den = 1;  // Denominator: Factorials, 2!, 4!, 6!...
    float ans    = 1;  // Accumulated answer
    for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i += 2) {
        num *= x*x;
        den *= i*i-i;
        sgn *= -1;
        ans += num / den * sgn;
    }

    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's work. I decided sin() before cos(). Function sin() don't has 1. Thank you)

Answer (score 2):

Your `cos` function is plain wrong. The explanations are in the comments.

```
float cos(float x) {
  float anglerad = x * 3.14159265359 / 180; // multiply first, then divide, but 
                                            // it probably doesn't matter much here

  float result = 1;                         // initial result must be 1
  float sign = -1;                          // use proper naming

  for (int i = 2; i < 10; i += 2) {
    // you need power(anglerad,.... not power(result,...)
    result += power(anglerad, i) / factorial(i) * sign;

    sign *= -1;
  }

  return result;
}
```

The formula for cosine is `1-(x^2/2!) + (x^4/4!) + ...`

You tried to use `x-(x^2/2!) + (x^4/4!) + ...` which is wrong.

---

Some general remarks:

althogh the corrected `cos` function is correct, it is not very efficient.

- the repeated calls to the factorial function can be avoided, by using the result of the previous iteration. Remember: `x! = x * (x-1)!`. You even could use a table with hard coded values of the factorials from 2 to 10 (or some other upper bound if you want more iterations).
- the repeated calls to the power function can be avoided. Remember: `x^n = x * x^(n-1)`.
- you could use more iterations.
- you could use `double` instead of `float`.
- and possibly a few more things.

Comment: Could also start with `result = 0;` and `polar = 1;` and `for(i = 0`, but then the `factorial` function needs to be corrected to return 1 for `factorial(0)`.

Comment: OP's attempt was more wrong than you described, mainly due to passing the partial sum to `power`. So it was more like `x - (x^2/2!) + ((x - (x^2/2!))^4/4!) - ...`.

Comment: `x * 3.14159265359 / 180;`, `x * (3.14159265359 / 180);` and other variations are all moot as the calculation is done wastefully using `double` math.   Just use `x * (3.14159265359.0f / 180)`: one multiply, one rounding.

Answer (score 1):

Small error in cos function. Try this.

```
float mycos(float x){
    float result = 1.0;
    float polar = -1;
    float xrad = x * (3.14159265359 / 180.);

    for (int i = 2; i < 10; i += 2) {
        result += power(xrad, i) / (factorial(i) * polar);
        polar *= -1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You should explain what changes you've made and why.  Simply posting the code does not help much.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I would implement it in Java.  The code should be similar enough to C for you to translate easily.  No power or factorial calls needed.  I hope you'll agree that it's much simpler.

```
public class TrigTaylorSeries {

    /**
     * Taylor series for cosine
     * @param x angle in radians
     * @param n terms to include (must be greater than zero)
     * @return cosine(x)
     * @link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series
     */
    public static double cos(double x, int n) {
        if (n <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number of terms must be positive");
        double result = 0.0;
        double factor = 1.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            result += factor;
            factor *= -x*x/(2*i+1)/(2*i+2);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here's a Junit test that shows it working correctly:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class TrigTaylorSeriesTest {

    @Test
    public void testCosine() {
        // setup
        int nterms = 20;
        int npoints = 20;
        double t = 0.0;
        double dt = 2.0*Math.PI/npoints;
        double eps = 1.0e-9;
        // exercise
        // assert
        for (int i = 0; i < npoints+1; ++i) {
            Assertions.assertEquals(Math.cos(t), TrigTaylorSeries.cos(t, nterms), eps, String.format("Incorrect result for %d", i));
            t += dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Accurate to nine significant figures using 20 terms.